# Proof showing $S$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Consider the normed space $ℓ^∞$ of bounded sequences and its subset
> $S =\{(x_n) : |x_n| ≤ \frac{1}{n} \mathrm{\;for\;all\;} n\}$. Prove that $S$ is closed.

I know $S$ is closed $\iff x^{(k)} \rightarrow x \in l^{\infty}$ and $x^{(k)} \in S, \; \forall k \implies x \in S$.
But why does it suffice to assume $$x^{(k)} \rightarrow x \in l^{\infty}$$ already holds, and only need to prove $x^{(k)} \in S, \; \forall k \implies x \in S$?

Comment: What do you mean? The latter is equivalent to $S$ being closed, and so it's sufficient to prove it. It's not very clear what are you asking.

Comment: It suffices to prove the latter because, as you said it, it is *equivalent* to the fact that $S$ is closed.

Comment: Why can we suppose that x^(k) --> x already? Don't we have to prove this as well?

Comment: That's the definition of a closed set. It's not that every sequence converges, but rather that if it does, it converges to something in the set.